# Udacity Sunshine android app - make ForecastFragment implement LoaderCallbacks - won't compile

Tags: java, android, fragment, loader

I am on lesson 4b of the Udacity course and have made all the changes to ForecastFragment.java to use the Loader but now the build fails here in MainActivity.java, even though I haven't touched that file.

Namely this part is underlined,

```
.add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
```

with the error:

```
Error:(20, 21) error: no suitable method found for add(int,ForecastFragment) method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment) method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable    (argument mismatch; ForecastFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

Here is the ForecastFragment declaration (and relevant imports as it is emphasized that the v4 versions must be used:)

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;

public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment
    implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
```

Interestingly, though I know it's incorrect, when I change the Fragment import to:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

The error in MainActivity.java goes away, but then it's ForecastFragment that won't compile, with initLoader() underlined and the error:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

Error:(281, 27) error: method initLoader in class LoaderManager cannot be applied to given types; required: int,Bundle,LoaderCallbacks<D> found: int,<null>,ForecastFragment
```

reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) D (argument mismatch; ForecastFragment cannot be converted to LoaderCallbacks) where D is a type-variable: D extends Object declared in method initLoader(int,Bundle,LoaderCallbacks)

Here's the full MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

I've gone back to my revert point from before the whole exercise of changing things to use a Loader twice now, to make sure I didn't just miss anything but I am at a loss.  Does anyone know what's going on?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) (or [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) if you want a backward compatible [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)) and [getSupportFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) if you want to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

The other option, of course, is to use the non-support v4 versions of `Fragment` and `LoaderManager`.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please elaborate on what I need to change?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use the support library versions or not? If not, then you should just be able to delete the two imports and replace them with the non support library versions (i.e., `android.app.Fragment` and `android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`).

Comment: I have to use the support library.  Is there something wrong with my class declaration or the instantionation?  Ugh!  Thanks

Comment: Ah, well that's even easier - replace `MainActivity extends Activity` with `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`.

Comment: And you also switched to `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `getSupportLoaderManager()` like my answer said?

Comment: I've updated my answer - from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment, it is just `getLoaderManager()`, not `getSupportLoaderManager()` - my apologies (it would be `getSupportLoaderManager()` only if you were loading directly in the activity).